# setting time interval on google timeline chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a google timeline chart with  a lot of info per line and I need to set the chart to display in hourly intervals.
Does anyone know how to set that option for the timeline chart
I have looked here [timeline options on google api page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#Configuration_Options)

but cannot see where to set the interval to lets say hourly

Thanks All

Comment: I believe the interval is determined by the range of your earliest and latest date in the chart. Maybe you could set it up as in the example for 'overlapping gridlines'.
setting the Date object on (0,0,0,hours,minutes,0)

Comment: does that include times or just the actual day value?

Comment: I have edited my comment, to be a little more explicit. :)
Maybe try this option
 `library: {hAxis:  { format: "hh. mm." } }`

or have a look here [dateformat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformatter)

Comment: did you find any solutions to this?